# Cannot auth or inject dependency with webapi, oauth, owin and ninject

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, ninject, owin

I have the following startup code

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
   var config = new HttpConfiguration();
   var kernel = NinjectConfig.CreateKernel();
   app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => kernel);
   app.UseNinjectWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
   OAuthConfig.Configure(app, kernel);
   WebApiConfig.Register(config);
   app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

with this I can authorize without problems but I cannot inject dependency it throws

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DummyController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

if I use this setup in the startup method

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
   var config = new HttpConfiguration();
   var kernel = NinjectConfig.CreateKernel();
   app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => kernel);
   app.UseNinjectWebApi(config); //THIS LINE CHANGED
   OAuthConfig.Configure(app, kernel);
   WebApiConfig.Register(config);
   //app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

the authorization fails, but if I remove the authorization attribute from the controller de dependency injection works

What am I missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The right config

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    var kernel = NinjectConfig.CreateKernel();
    app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => kernel);
    OAuthConfig.Configure(app, kernel);
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseNinjectWebApi(config);
}
```

Just call UseNinjectWebApi at the end of the Configuration  this method calls UseWebApi, now is all okay